# Maven deploy error 'Could not find artifact'

Tags: java, maven, deployment, github-package-registry

I was trying to use the github packages, I followed all the steps in their basic tutorial, but I can't deploy, I already looked on several sites to fix this, but none worked.

Error on deploy:

> Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact

My **settings.xml** (is from github packages tutorial):

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>github</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>github</id>
                    <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/HenryFabio/maven-packages/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>github</id>
            <username>HenryFabio</username>
            <password>my token =)</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

My **pom.xml** (this is only a test project):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.henryfabio</groupId>
    <artifactId>github-packages</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>github</id>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/HenryFabio/maven-packages/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

**stacktrace**:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:
deploy (default-deploy) on project github-packages: Failed to deploy artifacts:
Could not find artifact com.henryfabio:github-packages:jar:1.0 in github (https:
//maven.pkg.github.com/HenryFabio/maven-packages/) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on proje
ct github-packages: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact com.henr
yfabio:github-packages:jar:1.0 in github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/HenryFabi
o/maven-packages/)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav
a:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor
Impl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
25)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347
)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to deploy arti
facts: Could not find artifact com.henryfabio:github-packages:jar:1.0 in github
(https://maven.pkg.github.com/HenryFabio/maven-packages/)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBui
ldPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav
a:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor
Impl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
25)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347
)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Faile
d to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact com.henryfabio:github-packages:ja
r:1.0 in github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/HenryFabio/maven-packages/)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (Defaul
tArtifactDeployer.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployM
ojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBui
ldPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav
a:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor
Impl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
25)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347
)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy a
rtifacts: Could not find artifact com.henryfabio:github-packages:jar:1.0 in gith
ub (https://maven.pkg.github.com/HenryFabio/maven-packages/)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.
java:301)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.
java:213)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultR
epositorySystem.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (Defaul
tArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployM
ojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBui
ldPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav
a:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor
Impl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
25)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347
)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find
 artifact com.henryfabio:github-packages:jar:1.0 in github (https://maven.pkg.gi
thub.com/HenryFabio/maven-packages/)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFail
ed (ArtifactTransportListener.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.ru
n (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.put (BasicRep
ositoryConnector.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.
java:295)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.
java:213)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultR
epositorySystem.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (Defaul
tArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployM
ojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBui
ldPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347
)
```

Comment: add `-e` to the maven command and post the stacktrace to the question.

Comment: 9 times out of 10, I'd wager there's a plugin not compatible with your current java-version

Comment: how could you check? I'm using the standards

Comment: Any solution? I'm facing the same issue. :-(